# Domain Logic on API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm designing a public API for a system. I'm having doubts where should I put calculations or domain logic, should it reside on the API or on the client that will consume it?

Let say we have a Banking System, where should I put the logic for calculating cash amounts? Shall the consumer only call the Deposit method of the API and let the API handle the 
calculations?

API will be built using ASP.NET WebApi

Thanks

Comment: Is this API going to be consumed by external applications (that is, applications outside of your development), or internal applications which you also build and deploy?

Comment: Hello David, actually both. We can have our own Banking System and sell it then others might be interested developing they're own banking system thus using the API

Comment: In that case, if others are going to be consuming the API, then it would only make sense to put internal business logic behind the API. If it's external-facing then you can't assume consuming clients will implement the business logic, nor should they have to. If it was purely sandboxed and you deployed consuming applications then you could put the business logic on both sides, sharing the same domain models with server-side and client-side applications. (The CSLA framework operates much like this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your issue here but the business logic should be handled by the API (I wonder how the reverse would be).

From the implementation standpoint, you should handle them as services to decouple the system so that you can unit test it easily. For example, the below one is your `CalcService`:

```
public interface ICalcService { 

    double Calc(double left, double right);
}

public class CalcService : ICalcService {

    public double Calc(double left, double right) { 

        return (left + right);
    }
}
```

Then, this service should be injected into your controller as below:

```
public DepositController : ApiController { 

    private readonly ICalcService _calcService;

    public DepositController(ICalcService calcService) { 

        _calcService = calcService;
    }

    //now, you can use the _calcService inside your action methods
}
```

To make it work, you should register your service through your IoC container.

Comment: Thanks tugberk for an example. Yes I'm leaning towards putting the logic on the API but as I develop the API and the flagship product that will consume it, it seems I'm duplicating the logic on both sides specially the validations.

Comment: ASP.NET Web API has a validation system built in. You should go through this example project which is built against the RC: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Contact-Manager-Web-API-0e8e373d and this TechEd NA 2012 session: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV309